# difference between Python's bisect.bisect_left and C++'s std::upper_bound

Tags: python, c++

I have encountered a question:
Given two arrays X and Y of positive integers, find number of pairs such that x^y > y^x (raised to power of) where x is an element from X and y is an element from Y.

I tried to make the following code:

```
#code
import bisect

def pairs(ar1,ar2,n,m):
    count=0
    zeros=ar2.count(0)
    ones=ar2.count(1)
    twos=ar2.count(2)
    threes=ar2.count(3)
    fours=ar2.count(4)
    for x in ar1:
        if x==0:
            continue

        elif x==1:
            count+=zeros
            continue

        idx=bisect.bisect_left(ar2,x)
        if idx<m:
            if ar2[idx]==x:
                count+=m-idx-1
            else:
                count+=m-idx

        count+=zeros+ones

        if x==2:
            count-=threes+fours

        if x==3:
            count+=twos

    return count
```

but some test cases aren't
I have tried to emulate this code from C++

```
int count(int x, int Y[], int n, int NoOfY[])
{
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    if (x == 1) return NoOfY[0];
    int* id = upper_bound(Y, Y + n, x);
    cout << x<<"  "<<*id<<endl;
    int ans = (Y + n) - id;
    ans += (NoOfY[0] + NoOfY[1]);
    if (x == 2)  ans -= (NoOfY[3] + NoOfY[4]);
    if (x == 3)  ans += NoOfY[2];
    return ans;
}
int countPairs(int X[], int Y[], int m, int n)
{
    int NoOfY[5] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (Y[i] < 5)
            NoOfY[Y[i]]++;
    sort(Y, Y + n);
    int total_pairs = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
        total_pairs += count(X[i], Y, n, NoOfY);
    return total_pairs;
}
```

Please Help

Comment: You meant than C++ version is working but not python? both failed?

Comment: "some test cases aren't"... aren't what?  What test cases are you referring to?

Comment: No, the python code was not working. But, changed the bisect_left to bisect_right and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs of `bisect_left`:

> The returned insertion point `i` partitions the array a into two halves so that `all(val < x for val in a[lo:i])` for the left side and `all(val >= x for val in a[i:hi])` for the right side.

From the docs of `upper_bound`:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range `[first, last)` that is **greater** than `value`, or `last` if no such element is found.

Which can be stated as

> `all(val <= x for val in a[lo:i])` for the left side and `all(val > x for val in a[i:hi])` for the right side.

Note that bisect_left is using `>=`, but `upper_bound` is using `>`.

The equivalent to `upper_bound` is `bisect_right` not `bisect_left`

Comment: @KumarShaswat: If so, don't forget to hit the check mark next to the answer